# Different data sources for UnitOfWork and Repository patterns

Tags: c#, design-patterns, repository

I was involved in some code-review discussions about `UnitOfWork` and `Repository` pattern implementation with EF, which put me in some sort of confusion.

Yes, I know that EF already implements `UnitOfWork` and `Repository` pattern, but the question is not about that. I am just asking for your opinion regarding existing code base.

Let's start with `IUnitOfWork` interface declaration:

```
public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
{

    void CommitTransaction();
    IEnumerable<DbEntityValidationResult> Errors();
    dynamic Repository<TEntityType>() where TEntityType : BaseEntity;

}
```

1. I do not really like that `IUnitOfWork` declared as `IDisposable`. For me it looks like leaky abstraction, why should my UnitOfWork be `Disposable` if it isn't by his nature?
2. I also do not like the `Errors()` method. First of all it introduces dependency on `DbEntityValidationResult` class, which I do not want in my generic `IUnitOfWork` interface. I would prefer my newly created `Commit()` method to return my *custom* `ValidationResult` class, which will act as mapping for `DbEntityValidationResult`.

   Something like this:

   ```
    IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Commit();
   ```
3. The last thing is return value of `Repository<T>()` method. I don't like dynamic object, which is returned. I want some interface to be returned from such method, like `IRepository<T>` (I will ask about that a bit later).

Now let's move to the implementation. I will highlight some thing, that looks strange to me.

As soon as `IUnitOfWork` is declared as `IDisposable` the concrete implementation of `IUnitOfWork` implements some sort of `Disposable` pattern:

```
    private bool _disposed;

    ~UnitOfWork()
    {
        SharedDispose(false);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        SharedDispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    private void SharedDispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (_disposed || !disposing)
        {
            return;
        }
        _context.Dispose();
        _disposed = true;
    }
```

I do not see any reasons to have all this stuff. As soon as we do not own any unmanaged resources, we can skip all these destructors and all these instructions for `GC` to skip finalization queue for our unit of work object. Yes, we still need to implement `IDisposable` as soon as EF `DbContext` (which we own internally) implements it, but the implementation can be so much simpler:

```
    public void Dispose()
    {
        _context.Dispose();
        _context = null;
    }
```

Now let's see dynamic `Repository<T>()` implementation:

```
    public dynamic Repository<TEntityType>() where TEntityType : BaseEntity
    {
        if (_repositories == null)
        {
            _repositories = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        }

        var type = typeof(TEntityType).Name;
        var repositoryTypeName = typeof(UnitOfWork).Namespace + ".Repositories." + type + "Repository";
        var repoType = Type.GetType(repositoryTypeName);

        if (!_repositories.ContainsKey(type))
        {
            object repositoryInstance;
            if (repoType != null)
            {
                repositoryInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(repoType, _context);
            }
            else
            {
                var repositoryType = typeof(GenericRepository<>);
                repositoryInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(repositoryType.MakeGenericType(typeof(TEntityType)), _context);
            }
            _repositories.Add(type, repositoryInstance);
        }

        return repoType == null ? (GenericRepository<TEntityType>)_repositories[type] : Convert.ChangeType(_repositories[type], repoType);
    }
```

1. The method uses reflection to create specific repository for T-entity or returns `GenericRepository<T>` if there is no specific implementation defined. So the question is that a good practice to use reflection for that?
2. Another thing, why do we need this cache dictionary if unit of work object is injected in the scope of HTTP request?
3. How we can unify these repositories to get rid of dynamic object, which is returned right now?

My first idea was not to use specific repositories at all, instead create more sophisticated API for generic repository (which supports filtering, query object, paging and etc) and just return the interface like `IRepository<T>`. But not really sure if it is a good solution?
Beside this, the solution is using two data sources - the one is EF/Database and another one is web services. Web service repositories cannot so easily mapped to the `IRepository<T>` and most probably required some specific interface to be implemented.

What is the best practice to create repositories for two different data sources? How can we get rid of dynamic object? Do we need to create repositories for database and web services in the scope of one unit of work? Or should it be a separate one?

Comment: Simply said, `IDisposable` should be implemented by a class not by an interface.

Answer (score 2):

## The interface

I don't mind the IDisposable. If one implementation is designed that way and you retrieve it from the same factory as the other implementations, you really don't have a choice:

```
using(IUnitOfWork uow = UoW.GetDefault())
{
  // work...
}
```

`Errors`-property is ugly. A return value from `Commit` is better, an exception is best. The code should not be allowed to continue running when something fails.

The dependency on `DbEntityValidationResult` is not good, but allowing a custom type isn't any better for the same reasons. I think a `ValidationResult` should be defined in the same package and namespace as the `IUnitOfWork` interface.

Then the `dynamic` return type. Looks like someone declared a defeat right there. Why bother with the interface at all when you decide to go typeless?

## The implementation

The destructor calls `SharedDispose(false)`, which means `!disposing` is `true`, which then causes the method to return immediately. You can delete the destructor, it's a nop. Or a bug. Someone obviously tried to follow best practice and failed.

The reflection code used to create the repository looks like a poor man's DI container. Nothing wrong in that, if this is the only place you need this kind of functionality. But if there is a 'real' DI container in there somewhere, I suggest a refactoring.

The caching is probably introduced because reflection is 'slow'. But slow according to what? My guess is it's negligible compared to the actual repository usage. I would remove the cache unless someone actually profiled the code and can prove a significant improvement.

If all repositories have the same shape, then `dynamic` may be replaced by a generic interface. But if they don't, I can't see any way to unify them. If that's the case, I suggest replacing the generic `Repository()` with typed versions, like:

```
public FooRepository GetFooRepository() {}
public BarRepository GetBarRepository() {}
```

Then there's no longer need for the reflection stuff, as each method knows which one to create.

## A suggestion: Change abstraction level

It looks like the entity type used by DbContext is the domain class. That gives the following dependency:

```
Domain object -> DbContext
```

If that's true, then all the work done so far will not break the dependency, only hide it. I think all the problems with leaky abstractions also comes from that fact.

From the client point of view, we should see this:

```
Domain object -> Repository
```

From within the Repository we should see:

```
Domain object -> State DTO -> Entity -> DbContext
```

Depending on your needs, `State DTO` can be the `Entity`, or use the `Entity`, or be completely isolated from it.

The change here is that instead of persisting the domain object, the domain object will store its state to a new object, which is then persisted. This decouples the database schema from the domain object.

## Two different data sources

This suggests you have two bounded contexts where the domain objects may have the same name but address different aspects. I would accept the difference and let each boundary have their own set of classes pretending the other context does not exist:

A `Customer` in the `Shopping`-module is very different from the `Customer` in the `Invoicing`-module.

And by that, I think I have given my opinion on your last question: If some data lives in the database and some other in a web service, then you have two bounded context and you need two units of work. How to coordinate those two, I choose to be out of scope of this question...